# Overlay down arrow over coloured div / background image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a down arrow for the bottom of a full width div, which works great in the one instance below (where a coloured section runs into a white section):

[image]

But not for this instance...

[image]

The situation above has a blue div with a down arrow going into a full width background image. As you can see it doesn't quite work.

**I want the tip of the arrow to lay over the top of the image... or another colour. How can I do that?**

Here's my setup:

```
<div class="bannerStripHeader" style="background-color:#009edb;">
    <section class="row">           
        <div class="columns large-12" style="color:inherit !important;">
            <div class="brandHeaderContent">
                Content here    
            </div>
        </div>      
    </section>
</div>
```

I'm using the border colour to set it to white.

```
.bannerStripHeader:before {
border-width: 50px 0 30px 70vw;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
left: -5px;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
transform: rotateZ(0deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.bannerStripHeader:after {
border-width: 50px 70vw 30px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
right: -5px;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
transform: rotateZ(0deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.bannerStripHeader:after,
.bannerStripHeader:before {
content: "";
border-style: solid;
bottom: -23px;
height: 0;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease .5s;
transition: transform .5s ease .5s;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description and the code you provided don't really match well so I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you trying to achieve something like this demo?

```css
.bannerStripHeader {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bannerStripHeader:before {
  border-width: 50px 50vw 0 50vw;
  border-color: #009edb transparent transparent transparent;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}


/* only for demo */
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerStripHeader">
  <section class="row">
    <div class="columns large-12">
      <div class="brandHeaderContent">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427477321886-abc24e8ce923?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Kinda found it tricky to explain! It's within Wordpress so that html block repeats down the page with various content. Have you just overlayed the arrow over the top of the image?